# Catch first zero by regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string:

`0012309test07`

and I want to find the first zeros and letters.

**00** 12309 **test** 07

Sure I found letters with `/[^\d]/`, [here's the sample](http://rubular.com/r/9QFNXHW5dU).

But how do you catch the first zeros ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use this regexp `\b0+|[a-zA-Z]+`

Comment: @epascarello: No, it wouldn't. That's what the `\b` is for.

Comment: @Denis `[^\d]` also get spaces

Comment: There is no space before the 07, that's only because of his formatting in the question to show you the parts. He shows the real string first: `0012309test07`

Comment: Deleted the comments since I looked at the "formatted" version which does have the spaces.

Comment: 0012309test07 00secondtime here it also matches second time at 00

Answer (score 1):

use this pattern

```
(^(0*))|([a-zA-Z]+)
```

Answer (score 0):

`"0012309test07".match(/^(0*)(\d*)([^\d]+)(\d*)$/)`

output: `["0012309test07", "00", "12309", "test", "07"]`

`"12309test07".match(/^(0*)(\d*)([^\d]+)(\d*)$/)`

output: `["12309test07", "", "12309", "test", "07"]`

`"test07".match(/^(0*)(\d*)([^\d]+)(\d*)$/)`

output: `["test07", "", "", "test", "07"]`

`"0test07".match(/^(0*)(\d*)([^\d]+)(\d*)$/)`

output: `["0test07", "0", "", "test", "07"]`

`"1test07".match(/^(0*)(\d*)([^\d]+)(\d*)$/)`

output: `["1test07", "", "1", "test", "07"]`

`"test".match(/^(0*)(\d*)([^\d]+)(\d*)$/)`

output: `["test", "", "", "test", ""]`